# Macro to paste in dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy data table from one workbook into another. I figured out how to set the Copying range, but am struggling with a destination range which is dynamic.

For better understanding; Copying Document includes a set of values ordered by dates. Sometimes the data set will start with 1-jan, sometimes with 5-oct or any other random date.

Destination Document is a table of fixed dates from 1-jan until 31-dec and the data needs to be pasted in the correct row (according to the matching date). The columns are fixed.

I have a MATCH formula in the Destination Document to crosscheck in which row the Paste Range should start, but don't know how to combine it with the already known column.

For now I have:

```
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("PATHWAY 1")
Set y = ThisWorkbook

x.Sheets("2").Range("B1:F1").End(xlDown).Copy

'Now, paste to y worksheet:
y.Sheets("R2").Range.Cells("2,[Helper.xlsb]R2!$H$2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

[image: Data Sets Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for.

```
dim m as variant

x.Sheets("2").Range("B1:F1").End(xlDown).Copy
m = application.match(dateserial(2018, 10, 31), y.range("A:A"), 0)
if not iserror(m) then
    y.Sheets("R2").Cells(m, "B").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
end if
```

Comment: It gives the syntax error. Is there any way to define the starting row of the paste range with a MATCH function?